# Adding class to label when clicking on input

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the thing i have different spans and one input and one label for each span. What i want is when i click on the input it must add a class to the label.

```css
.in {position: relative; background: none}
.lb {position: absolute; color: #000; z-index: 1}
.outer {display: block; width: 100%; margin: 60px}
.color {color: green}
```

```html
<span class="outer">
  <label class="lb">hi there</label>
  <input class="in" type="text">
</span>

<span class="outer">
  <label class="lb">hi there</label>
  <input class="in" type="text">
</span>

<span class="outer">
  <label class="lb">hi there</label>
  <input class="in" type="text">
</span>
```

Comment: Don't need JS/jQuery for this.

Comment: so how to do this.

Comment: First tell me what's the point of adding a class, pure styling?

Comment: as you can see the label is at the backside of input i want to add a class transform:translatey(-100%); so it will go at the  top when someone click on the input .

Answer (score 4):

```js
$( "input" ).focus(function() {
  $( this ).parent().find( "label").addClass("focus");
  $( this ).parent().addClass(" focus-span");
});

$( "input" ).focusout(function() {
  $( this ).parent().find( "label").removeClass("focus");
  $( this ).parent().removeClass(" focus-span");
});
```

```css
.in{position:relative; backgorund:none;  }
.lb{position:absolute; color:#000; z-index:1;}
.outer{display:block; width:100%; margin:60px;  }
 .color{color:green;}
 .focus{
   color:red;
 }
 .focus-span{
   border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<span class="outer">
<label class="lb">hi there</label>
<input  class="in" type="text"/>
</span>

<span class="outer">
<label class="lb">hi there</label>
<input  class="in" type="text"/>
</span>

<span class="outer">
<label class="lb">hi there</label>
<input  class="in" type="text"/>
</span>

 

 
</body>
</html>
```

Revert code add on focus out too also add some css to view changes
Hope you will find your solution

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```css
.in {background: none} /* removed the position, don't need it */
.lb {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; color: #000; z-index: 1}
.outer {position: relative; display: block; width: 100%; margin: 60px} /* added the position, need it to affect the label */
.color {color: green}

.in:focus + .lb {
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="outer">
  <input class="in" type="text" id="inp1">
  <label class="lb" for="inp1">hi there</label>
</span>

<span class="outer">
  <input class="in" type="text" id="inp2">
  <label class="lb" for="inp2">hi there</label>
</span>

<span class="outer">
  <input class="in" type="text" id="inp3">
  <label class="lb" for="inp3">hi there</label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)
    {
        $('span.outer').on('click', function()
        {
            $(this).addClass('foo')
        })
    })
</script>
```

this will add a class (called foo) to the clicked span with class outer.

refs: https://api.jquery.com/addClass/

edit after re-reading question

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)
    {
        $('span.outer').on('click', function()
        {
            $(this).closest('label').addClass('foo')
        })
    })
</script>
```

refs:
https://api.jquery.com/closest/